# Colors for a diagram with unknown number of categories

Tags: color, color-theory, diagram

I have to draw a diagram for dynamic data. Each category should have a different color, but I don't know how many categories the diagram is going to show.

I expect this number typically to be between 5 and 10, but more or less is possible. Is there a strategy for choosing the diagram colors in this case, so that

- they are distinguishable,
- they do not hurt the eye,
- they do not create affiliations where there are none?

I thought of the following:

- Choose one color and use tints/shades

  *PRO*: fits in well with the rest of the website

  *CON*: hard to distinguish
- Choose a few colors and use tints/shades

  *PRO*: fits in well with the rest of the website, probably enough colors to be distinguishable for the expected amount of categories

  *CON*: the different colors impose an unwanted meaning, e.g. greenish categories somehow belong together and are different from blueish categories
- Choose a few colors and use additional patterns

  *PRO*: like the above

  *CON*: like the above, with meaning not only in colors but also in patterns
- Choose a few colors and repeat

  *PRO*: fits in well with the rest of the website

  *CON*: one color stands for multiple categories
- Try to find different colors for all categories (speaking of hues)

  *PRO*: distinguishable for the expected amount of categories

  *CON*: off-putting, not easy to calculate

There must be an approach to this problem? I've been searching and thinking for days, but couldn't find a satisfying solution.

You can think of the diagram as a (stacked) bar chart. Other types are possible, although I think this would not essentially change the question (or answers). Of course, the diagram will also be equipped with a legend and tooltips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a very similar thing in [a project of mine](https://github.com/ZachSaucier/JABS). In it, I used [this color library](https://github.com/davidmerfield/randomColor) to generate some colors for me. If you view [the demo](https://zachsaucier.com/procedural-agent-based-simulator.html), you'll see the colors being used. It essentially does your second method, "Choose a few colors and use tints/shades".

To reduce the number of similar colors that are hard to distinguish, you can use an algorithm to see how close together they are and generate a new color for ones below a certain threshold (make sure that the threshold is actually achievable given the number of colors you need). You can find a very simple one (checking a linear difference, which isn't how we *perceive* color change<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019461/2065702),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5392276/2065702)</sup>, but is really easy to implement) in [my color picker project](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/vKwVmb?editors=0010).

You can also generate sub-sets of colors for related categories. Since you provide no information about said categories, it's hard to give advice as to *how* to do so.

---

But from a design perspective, I may not do it this way. It depends on the types of data that you have. If you have a set number of category always, I'd likely choose some set color palette and link each color to a category one-to-one. More details could be helpful in determining whether or not this is preferable.

Comment: The categories are not related and cannot be grouped further. And the number of categories can in theory range from 0 to infinity :/ But your project sounds very useful, I'm going to take a closer look at it, thank you very much!

Comment: After thinking about it for a while, I came to the conclusion that it's not perfect that the colors change (drastically) with every refresh in my application. Maybe I can combine your approach with other techniques and make it a little more static or deterministic.

Comment: You could generate a set that's above your current max number of items (say, 20 or 30) once and pair it with a category. Then keep that same color for the category permanently